# Trigger the comparevalidator everytime the value of the controltocompare changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, comparevalidator

I have a comparevalidator for my calendar extender. The textbox that's set as controltocompare changes value whenever the user checks/unchecks boxes inside a gridview. How do I trigger the comparevalidator from code behind everytime the checkedchanged event is triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all it is not clear from your question what you want to compare.
Second Compare validators fires on its own. you cant make it to fire on check box change. instead you can write server side code to achieve that. hope it helps.

Comment: Ah yes, I'm sorry. I was asking for a way to trigger it from the code behind. I'm trying to compare the date picked from the calendar extender with the date inside the textbox which changes depending on what checkboxes the user checks.

Comment: if you want to trigger from code behind. set checkbox's autpostback property to true. and write an event handler in code behind like below:                                         <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="checkChanged" />                                and in code behind:  write an event handler for the same with name as : "checkChanged"

Comment: I already have that. What I'm asking for is the line of code that will fire the comparevalidator from code behind. So as to check if the selected date from the calendar extender is still valid. I'm assuming this is possible. Or isn't it? And by valid I mean it's later/greater than the latest date among the values of the checked checkboxes.